# Covariance of stochastic integrals - Poisson stochastic process -

Tags: stochastic-integrals, covariance, poisson-process, moment-generating-functions

I'm trying to improve my understanding on inhomogeneous Poisson processes. In particular, I'm focusing on stochastic integrals of the form 
$$I(T)=\int_0^Tf(t)dW_t$$ with $W_t$ arrival times of a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda_t$.
Most of all, I would like to compute expectation values of such integrals, namely $\mathbb{E}[I]$, $\mathbb{E}[I^2]$.

I've collected some results from related problems:

- [Covariance](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2365720/197855) with $f(t)=1$
- [Attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2587999/197855) to compute $I(T)$ with $\lambda_t=\mu e^{\lambda t},\mu>0$ and $f(t)=e^{\alpha (T-t)}, \alpha>0$
- [Calculating](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27687/197855) $\mathbb{E}[I]$
- [Using Rieman-Stieltjes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27710/197855) integration for $\mathbb{E}[I]$

And among all [computing the moment generating function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/359346/197855) $\mathbb{E}[e^{\beta I}]$ for an **homogeneous** Poisson process.

However none of them provide explicitly $\mathbb{E}[I^2]$, or $\mathbb{E}[e^{\beta I}]$ for the **inhomogeneous** case. I would appreciate if someone would provide examples for specific $f(t), \lambda(t)$, explicit generic expressions, or instructions to compute them myself.

Note: this is related to an [attempt](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444151/variance-of-integral-of-poisson-variables) in a less precise approach, which apparently leads to contradictory results.